# How to set up sbt-assembly to include jars with runtime scope?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

How to set up sbt-assembly to include jars with runtime scope? What's the rationale for not doing it by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now being discussed under [sbt/sbt-assembly#120](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/120).

sbt-assembly is intended to wire full classpath from `Runtime` configuration. And it's coded as follows:

```
fullClasspath in assembly <<= fullClasspath or (fullClasspath in Runtime),
```

For Spark, for whatever reason `fullClasspath` is wired, so that's likely interfering. The reason sbt-assembly included `fullClasspath` I think is now historical, so I might get rid of "fullClasspath or" part. As noted in the issue, the current workaround is likely:

```
fullClasspath in assembly := (fullClasspath in Runtime).value
```

FYI for those who learn sbt the above sbt-0.13+ format with `:=` corresponds to the older pre-sbt-0.13 format with `:=` as follows:

```
fullClasspath in assembly <<= (fullClasspath in Runtime)
```

Comment: How was it figured out that the question applies to Spark? Where did it come from? It was not clear from the question, was it?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I'm not sure if this question is related, but see the linked issue #120.

Comment: Well, I have read the issue, but was wondering how you knew the OP asked about the particular issue and when you used *For Spark* how you knew it's related to Spark?

Comment: `in` is  deprecated in latest sbt. how to rewrite `fullClasspath in assembly := (fullClasspath in Runtime).value
`

Answer (score 1):

My tests show that the plugin does **include** dependencies with `runtime` scope as evidenced with the following example.

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2" % "runtime"

assemblySettings
```

This is a sample session:

```
> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.6-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is {file:/C:/dev/sandbox/runtime-assembly/}runtime-assembly 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.4
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin, sbtassembly.Plugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
> assembly
[info] Updating {file:/C:/dev/sandbox/runtime-assembly/}runtime-assembly...
[info] Resolving org.jacoco#org.jacoco.agent;0.6.4.201312101107 ...
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.2!logback-classic.jar (1122ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.1.2!logback-core.jar (1313ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Including: slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
[info] Including: logback-classic-1.1.2.jar
[info] Including: logback-core-1.1.2.jar
[info] Including: scala-library.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[info] SHA-1: 0f520cdfc30de8ced8408a3c25b326b3ff5afda8
[info] Packaging C:\dev\sandbox\runtime-assembly\target\scala-2.10\runtime-assembly-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
```

Jar verification:

```
/cygdrive/c/dev/sandbox/runtime-assembly
$ jar -tf target/scala-2.10/runtime-assembly-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep logback | wc -l
592
```